# How can I make this into a better dashboard?

Tags: critique, information-design, data-visualisation, information-architecture

I need to redesign a link and text heavy dashboard to make it more useable and aesthetically pleasing. The existing page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's basically a dump of links to other reports, with a little bit of grouping and some preview of the aggregated data. I think this is hard to use because it's not clear what all of the links do, and it's unattractive and just plain overwhelming with text.

What would be a better way to lay this out to show some useful dashboard type data and provide intuitive drill down for more reports and charts?

Comment: For a starter on dashboard design, see this [other question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/ergonomic-standards-to-design-ui)

Comment: Personally, I think its extremely clear: I have no prior knowledge and I can take this in pretty easily. I *can* see a few ways to reduce text: wherever there is a phrase repeated, that could be a subhead. As far as making it more attractive, there is a lot of double+ emphasis: color, line, space, size. Pick two, maybe size and space

Comment: @Yorik: I guess it's clear, but don't you think all that text tires the eyes and buries the important stuff among the less important stuff? There couldn't really be 20 or so equally important places to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a re-design I would create a sitemap of the site to determine the hierarchy effectively.  There is too much text there and it needs to be dialed down.  Even if you remove the links you will be facing an issue with ""how many clicks does it take".  If it takes a visitor, [if I recall from an article I read many years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-click_rule), more then three clicks then your site should be re-factored.

You need to ask your client if they are ok with changing the overall site.  Since you do not have the full site displayed and are asking for advise I would look into testing an accordion.  Personally I wouldn't have the team stats in that manner.  It would make great site fill, such as the top players in a related area but you shouldn't have to display all those counts like that in an area that will confuse or draw from the navigation.

Comment: We are free to redesign this however we want, I'm just not sure how to do it. I know in general that I want to present a dashboard with basic metrics (perhaps configurable to the user's main interests), and provide intuitive drilling down to more detailed views. There are just so many ways to go that I don't know where to start.